# Simple polygon in cocos3d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am trying to implement a simple 3d object on the cocos3d template.

Usually you get the object from a POD file or similar.

But what i need is to make it by code in the application.

I have tried CC3BoxNode with CC3BoundingBox. But it isn't what I am looking for.

I need to create something similar to that.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this example: [Bigbot Smash City](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/andyman/bigbot-smash-city/posts/88032)

Comment: in ios5, i got compilation error at the line CC3Layer* cc3Layer = [[Demo3DLayer alloc] initWithColor: ccc4(0x00,0x9a,0xcd,0xff)] autorelease]; in appdelegate and i changed it to CC3Layer* cc3Layer = [[Demo3DLayer alloc] init]; and got it working. hope it will help somebody. Thanks for the example link.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this ?

`CC3BoundingBox bounds = makeBounds(9.5, 5.0, 4.0, 0, 0, 0);
CC3MeshNode *cube = [[CC3MeshNode alloc] init];
[cube populateAsSolidBox:bounds];`

This is the way the boxes are created in the project cited above.
I've been playing around with the project and extracted the code to draw just a simple box like this :

[image: Simple cube display with Cocos3D]

Cheers,